# Property 'property' does not exist on type (interface1 | interface2)

Tags: typescript, eslint

I got error fom eslint:

Property 'type' does not exist on type MenuItemA | MenuItemB

```
 private menuPagesFiltered: (MenuItemA | MenuItemB )[] =  [..some data]

    this.menuPagesFiltered.map(el => {
        if (el.type === 'wrapper') {  <= error here
        }
    })

   export interface MenuItemA {
       title: string;
       open: boolean;
       type: 'wrapper';
   }

   export interface MenuItemB {
       title: string;
       id?: string;
       url: string;
       icon: string;
   }
```

*code simplified

Without eslint it works fine, I have error when linting..

Answer (score 0):

You got a problem because

```
  Property 'type' does not exist on type 'MenuItemA | MenuItemB'.
  Property 'type' does not exist on type 'MenuItemB'.
```

So you have to check that el is of type MenuItemA to be able to access '.type' property

you can do it in 2 ways, with the 'in' keyword

```
if ('type' in el && el.type === 'wrapper')
```

or with a TypeGuard

```
function isA(x: MenuItemA | MenuItemB): x is MenuItemA {
  return (x as MenuItemA).type !== undefined;
}

 if (isA(el) && el.type === 'wrapper')
```

if you try to accede to 'title' for example, you don't have this problem because this property exists in both the MenuItem models.